# How do you find all the answers to this Diophantus equation: $462x + 273y = 63$?

Tags: diophantine-equations

How do you find all the answers to this Diophantus equation (only whole numbers): $462x + 273y = 63$  ?

I started with finding the gcd using the Euclidean Algorithm.
$\gcd(462;273)$
$462=1*273+189$
$273=1*189+84$
$189=2*84+21$
$84=4*21+0$
$\gcd(462;273)=21$
But how do I continue? I know that you can solve it because you can divide 63 by our gcd 21.

Comment: Any textbook on elementary number theory has a general formula for this type of problem.

Comment: Now extend your computation to the extended Euclidean algorithm in one of its versions, this finds numbers $u,v$ with $462u+273v=21$, the conclusion from that should be trivial.

Comment: You found out that gcd , so divide the equation by this gcd. If there is a solution, then the resulting equation must contain again only integer coefficients. here it is the more handy equivalent equation $$22x+13y=3$$ with the special solution $(9/-15)$. The rest should be easy.

Comment: @Peter Peter answers Peter!